# Non EU travelling with minor EU children to UK

Tags: visas, standard-visitor-visas, eu-citizens, minors, south-african-citizens

I'm a non EU citizen (South African) married to a EU citizen (Portuguese). We have a 5 year old and a 1 year old that both have EU passports. I would like to visit family in the UK, but will be travelling alone with my 2 children. What visa would I require? Could I apply for a EEA family permit or can I only apply for that if my husband was travelling with us? Or would I need to apply for a UK Standard Visitors Visa?

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need a Visitor Visa. You can only apply for a Family Permit if your husband is travelling to the UK with you. https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eligibility

Comment: @CDePao in particular, the directive and the UK's implementing regulations specify that a parent may derive a right of free movement from a child when the *parent* is dependent on the *child.*  The intention here is obviously to cover older parents of working-age EU citizens, not cases such as yours.  There are some court decisions that have expanded the free movement rights of non-EU parents of minors, but determining whether they would apply to your proposed trip (and, if so, invoking them to get an EEA family permit) would probably be more trouble than just getting a standard visitor visa.